# Заполнение таблицы с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
//Есть объект:

var section = {
  link: [],
  filename: [],
  name: [],
  author: [],
  material: [],
  scale: [],
  date: [],
  museum: [],
  city: [],
  notation: [],
};

console.log(section);
for (property in section) {
  section[property].forEach(function(item) {
    $('#painting > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>' + item + '</td></tr>');
  });
}
```

```html
<table id="painting" cellspacing="2" border="1" cellpadding="5">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Имя файла</th>
      <th>Название</th>
      <th>Автор</th>
      <th>Материал</th>
      <th>Размеры</th>
      <th>Дата создания</th>
      <th>Музей</th>
      <th>Страна, город</th>
      <th>Примечание</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

После его заполнения, я получаю массивы (количество элементов в них равное, соответственно). Потом пытаюсь заполнить таблицу:

И заполняется только первый столбец ("Имя файла"), всеми значениями. Как мне корректно заполнить таблицу?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="painting" cellspacing="2"  border="1" cellpadding="5">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Имя файла</th>
      <th>Название</th>
      <th>Автор</th>
      <th>Материал</th>
      <th>Размеры</th>
      <th>Дата создания</th>
      <th>Музей</th>
      <th>Страна, город</th>
      <th>Примечание</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

for (property in section) {
  section[property].forEach(function(item) {
    $('#painting > tbody tr:last-child').append('<td>' + item + '</td>');
  });
}
```

Comment: А так в одну линию выводится все.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (property in section) {
  var tr = '<tr>'; // создаем строку таблицы
  section[property].forEach(function(item) {
    tr += '<td>' + item + '</td>'; // добавляем столбцы в строку
  });
  tr += '</tr>'; // закрываем строку таблицы
  $('#painting > tbody:last-child').append(tr); // добавляем полученную строку в дом
}
```

Comment: Почему-то они слева-направо выводятся, а не сверху-вниз.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, какой конечный результат вам нужен.

Comment: Чтобы сверху-вниз: под "Имя файла" - link, под "Название" - filename... и так далее.

Comment: Каждый элемент из массива в отдельной ячейке? Или в одной ячейке все элементы массива?

Comment: Каждый элемент из массива в отдельной ячейке, по вертикали.

Comment: Попробуйте через цикл пройтись по массиву. Цикла будет 2: первый для столбцов и внутри него для строк. Заполняете сверху вниз все значения, после чего первый цикл переходит на второй столбец, а второй, отвечающий, за строки, снова заполняет таблицу сверху вниз. И так до конца

Answer (score 0):

```js
const section = {
  link: ['Link 1', 'Link 2'],
  filename: ['Filename 1', 'Filename 2'],
  name: ['Name 1', 'Name 2'],
  author: ['Author 1', 'Author 2'],
  material: ['Material 1', 'Material 2'],
  scale: ['Scale 1', 'Scale 2'],
  date: ['Date 1', 'Date 2'],
  museum: ['Museum 1', 'Museum 2'],
  city: ['City 1', 'City 2'],
  notation: ['Notation 1', 'Notation 2'],
};

/* 
Судя по всему, колонки для этого 
свойства в таблице не нашлось,
поэтому удаляем его
*/
delete section.link;

const flipMatrix = matrix => matrix[0].map((_, i) => matrix.map(row => row[i]));

const html = flipMatrix(Object.values(section)).map(row => row.map(col => `<td>${col}</td>`).join ``).join `<tr></tr>`;

painting.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML = `<tr>${html}</tr>`;
```

```html
<table id="painting" cellspacing="2" border="1" cellpadding="5">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Имя файла</th>
      <th>Название</th>
      <th>Автор</th>
      <th>Материал</th>
      <th>Размеры</th>
      <th>Дата создания</th>
      <th>Музей</th>
      <th>Страна, город</th>
      <th>Примечание</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Или просто:

```js
const section = {
  link: ['Link 1', 'Link 2'],
  filename: ['Filename 1', 'Filename 2'],
  name: ['Name 1', 'Name 2'],
  author: ['Author 1', 'Author 2'],
  material: ['Material 1', 'Material 2'],
  scale: ['Scale 1', 'Scale 2'],
  date: ['Date 1', 'Date 2'],
  museum: ['Museum 1', 'Museum 2'],
  city: ['City 1', 'City 2'],
  notation: ['Notation 1', 'Notation 2'],
};

delete section.link;

const maxLength = Object.values(section).map(a => a.length).reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b));

let html = '';
for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
  html += `
    <tr>
    <td>${section.filename[i] || '-'}</td>
    <td>${section.name[i] || '-'}</td>
    <td>${section.author[i] || '-'}</td>
    <td>${section.material[i] || '-'}</td>
    <td>${section.scale[i] || '-'}</td>
    <td>${section.date[i] || '-'}</td>
    <td>${section.museum[i] || '-'}</td>
    <td>${section.city[i] || '-'}</td>
    <td>${section.notation[i] || '-'}</td>
    </tr>`;
}
painting.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<table id="painting" cellspacing="2" border="1" cellpadding="5">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Имя файла</th>
      <th>Название</th>
      <th>Автор</th>
      <th>Материал</th>
      <th>Размеры</th>
      <th>Дата создания</th>
      <th>Музей</th>
      <th>Страна, город</th>
      <th>Примечание</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

P.S. Если длина массивов одинакова, то значение `maxLength` можно получить просто взяв длину массива любого свойства.